# Fail to send Quickblox group chat invitation message

Tags: ios, swift, quickblox

After successfully creating a group QBChatDialog, I try to sent invitation messages to all occupants by

```
if self.chatDialog.join() == true {
            for occupantID in self.chatDialog.occupantIDs {
                var inviteMessage = self.createChatNotificationForGroupChatCreation(self.chatDialog)

                var timestamp = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
                inviteMessage.customParameters["date_sent"] = timestamp

                // send notification
                //
                inviteMessage.recipientID = occupantID as! UInt
                //QBChat.instance().sendMessage(inviteMessage)
                //QBChatDialog.  sendMessage(inviteMessage)
                if self.chatDialog.sendMessage(inviteMessage) == true {
                    println("################# Send ok ######################")
                } else {
                    println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! error sending !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
                }
            }
            }
```

but I always get the error. It keeps telling me that "Room is not joined". I did join the room using "self.chatDialog.join()" command. I even check that the process is ok before I send the message. Please help.